# links not functioning since php 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting, register-globals

This may be a register_globals = on issue or url rewriting problem. I eliminated the url rewriting possibility by using basic php linking syntax. I tried several patches to emulate register_globals being on but to no avail. The site was functioning normally until last week when the php.ini file was updated. It is an Apache server with php 5.4.23.
Basically I have a catalog page which displays a list of works called from a mysql database. When the user clicks the link, it brings the user to the appropriate item page. The catalog list displays correctly but the links do not function anymore and there is not error displayed. It always links to the first item of the mysql request and not the link that is requested even though the url that is displayed is correct. 
Here is the code to connect to the database:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pw"); 
mysql_select_db("database_name",$db); 
$sqlNum = 'SELECT * FROM callejas ORDER BY engname ';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM callejas ORDER BY engname LIMIT '.(($page-1)).",".(1);
$resultNum = mysql_query($sqlNum);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($resultNum);
$sqlnext = 'SELECT * FROM callejas ORDER BY engname LIMIT ' .(($page)).",".(1);
$sqlpre = 'SELECT * FROM callejas ORDER BY engname LIMIT ' .(($page-2)).",".(1);
//sommaire
$req = 'SELECT * FROM callejas ORDER BY engname  '; 
$result = mysql_query($req); 
$result1 = mysql_num_rows($result);
$milieu =  $result1 / 2;
$mil = (int)$milieu ;
$left = 'SELECT * FROM callejas ORDER BY `engname`  ASC LIMIT 0,'.($mil);
$right = 'SELECT * FROM callejas ORDER BY `engname`  ASC LIMIT '.($mil).",".($result1);
?>
```

Here is part of the catalog.php file which functions correctly except for the link

```
    <?
include ("connecttodatabase.php");
$i=1;
$j=0;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div align="right" id="left" style="position:absolute; width:200px; height:388px; z-index:42; left: 6px; top: 170px;" class="interline30"> 
<?
$leftres = mysql_query($left);
function StandardizeString($img)
{
      $img = strtr($img,
             'ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ',
             'SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy' );
      $img = preg_replace('/[\'"]/', '',$img); // Eliminate all quotes
      $img = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $img); // Remove all spaces
      $img = trim($img, '_'); // Remove any leading or trailing underscored
      // Return the result
      return $img;
  }
while(($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($leftres)))
{
$img= $myrow['engleg'] ;
$little = "".$myrow['little'];
$tittle = StandardizeString($img); 
?>
<div align="center"
<?
echo  "id=\"$i\"";
?>
style="position:absolute; width:153px; z-index:49; left: 207px;top: 
<?
echo "$j px;"
?> 
visibility: hidden;"> 
<?
echo "<img src= \"{$little}\" title= \"{$img}\"  alt= \"{$img}\">";
?>
</div>
<?
echo "<p><a href='works.php?tittle=$tittle&page=$i' 
$img</a></p>";
$i++;
$j = $j+30;
}
?>
</div>
</body>
```

I have not been able to see what is wrong. This code has functioned for several years and after reading about the differences between php 5.3 and 5.4 I don't see any code that is deprecated
but I do know that register_globals was on.

Comment: Have you tried adding `/` before your url?

Comment: Just tried. No that doesn't work. Gives me a 404 error. As I said this has been working for several years.

Comment: Did you check that short_open_tag is enabled or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum...register_globals is DEPRECATED since PHP 5.3.0 and **REMOVED** in PHP 5.4"

Your problem lies certainly in this script : `works.php`

Please consider this quick and dirty fix : [register_globals fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141631/register-globals-fix)

Comment: The works.php file has not been changed either and was functioning. At this moment the link brings us to the works page but always displays the first item of the mysql query but the url that is displayed is correct.

Comment: The register_globals fix worked. I do understand that this is a very temporary solution and that I must clean up the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below lines in your code not closed. You can fix it by closing it with semi colon.

```
<?
echo "$j px;";
?>
```

also follow this SO answer to run your script like register global is enabled.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706242/817365

Comment: Fixed. Thank you, but doesn't help with the link problem.

Comment: Updated the post. You can follow that SO answer to get the register global functionality.